# android program to get exact location like google map?

Tags: android, location, tracking

Hi I wan't to get current location latitude and longitude.I have example but all are showing diff latitude and longitude (means + or - 50 mts Radious) but google map shows exact location can any give some example here is my code.

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks,
        OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

```
// LogCat tag
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 1000;

private Location mLastLocation;

// Google client to interact with Google API
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

// boolean flag to toggle periodic location updates
private boolean mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;

private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

// Location updates intervals in sec
private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 80000; // 8 sec
private static int FATEST_INTERVAL = 5000; // 5 sec
private static int DISPLACEMENT = 5; // 5 meters

// UI elements
private TextView lblLocation;
Context cont;
private Button btnShowLocation, btnStartLocationUpdates,check;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    cont=this;
    lblLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblLocation);
    check=(Button)findViewById(R.id.check);
    btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);
    btnStartLocationUpdates = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLocationUpdates);
    // First we need to check availability of play services
    if (checkPlayServices()) {
        // Building the GoogleApi client
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        createLocationRequest();
    }

    // Show location button click listener
    btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            displayLocation();
        }
    });

    // Toggling the periodic location updates
    btnStartLocationUpdates.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            togglePeriodicLocationUpdates();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    checkPlayServices();
    // Resuming the periodic location updates
if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
        startLocationUpdates();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    stopLocationUpdates();
}

/**
 * Method to display the location on UI
 * */
private void displayLocation() {

    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
            .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
        double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
        lblLocation.setText(latitude + ", " + longitude);

    } else {

        lblLocation
                .setText("(Couldn't get the location. Make sure location is enabled on the device)");
    }
}

/**
 * Method to toggle periodic location updates
 * */
private void togglePeriodicLocationUpdates() {
    if (!mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
        // Changing the button text
        btnStartLocationUpdates
                .setText(getString(R.string.btn_stop_location_updates));

        mRequestingLocationUpdates = true;

        // Starting the location updates
        startLocationUpdates();

        Log.d(TAG, "Periodic location updates started!");

    } else {
        // Changing the button text
        btnStartLocationUpdates
                .setText(getString(R.string.btn_start_location_updates));

        mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;

        // Stopping the location updates
        stopLocationUpdates();

        Log.d(TAG, "location tracker stopped!");
    }
}

/**
 * Creating google api client object
 * */
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .build();
}

/**
 * Creating location request object
 * */
protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FATEST_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);
    //mLocationRequest.
}

/**
 * Method to verify google play services on the device
 * */
private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "This device is not supported.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Starting the location updates
 * */
protected void startLocationUpdates() {

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}

/**
 * Stopping location updates
 */
protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, this);
}

/**
 * Google api callback methods
 */
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
            + result.getErrorCode());
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {

    // Once connected with google api, get the location
    displayLocation();

    if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
        startLocationUpdates();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // Assign the new location
    mLastLocation = location;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location changed!",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // Displaying the new location on UI
    displayLocation();
```

}
}
and manifest contains

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: What you're asking is not clear, please try to expand/clarify your question

Comment: do want to know how to find latitude and longitude of your current location??

Comment: in your question you mention you want something like google maps.. why not use [Google Maps API](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/maps.html)?

Comment: @bwegs I am using using Google map API  but It's  not showing Exact location like google map. It show my location around 100 mtr radios but google map shows exact location

Comment: Show us the code that you're using so that we can help

Comment: @bwegs I have added My code Please check and help Thank You...

Comment: finally got solution

Comment: @GPAdiga It has been a long now since you asked the question. But can you please share your solution?